# Haskell Stack fails to build with a blank error message

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am getting this error when trying to build a project in haskell stack. This is a mid-sized project with a number of packages. My best guess for what is causing the problem is that some of the packages have circular dependencies, but that is a guess.

```
stack --stack-yaml stacks/ghc/stack.yaml install

While constructing the build plan, the following exceptions were encountered:


Plan construction failed.
```

Comment: Looks like a bug to me. Please open an issue at https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues, ideally with a project that the bug can reproduced with!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely due to cyclic dependencies.  The error message has been fixed in the unreleased version of stack - see https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2583

Comment: that was the problem, good to know that the error msg has been fixed